# Problems with gensim WikiCorpus - aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial; (__mp_main__ instead of __main__?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nlp, gensim

I'm quite new to Python and coding in general, so I seem to have run into an issue.

I'm trying to run this code (credit to Matthew Mayo, whole thing can be found [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/11/building-wikipedia-text-corpus-nlp.html)):

```
# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings(action = 'ignore', category = UserWarning, module = 'gensim')
import sys
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

def make_corpus (in_f, out_f):
    print(0)
    output = open(out_f, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
    print(1)
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)
    print(2)
    i = 0
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '/n')
        i += 1
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print('Processed {} articles!'.format(i))
    print(3)
    output.close()
    print('Process complete!')



print('start')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Usage: python make_wiki_corpus.py <wikipedia_dump_file> <processed_text_file>')
        sys.exit(1)
    in_f = sys.argv[1]
    out_f = sys.argv[2]
    make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
else:
    print(__name__)
```

However, the function branch seems to run partly, stopping at the `wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)` - it never makes it to `print(2)` - and then exiting and repeating the beginning of the code, yielding no results. No error actually comes up, only a warning (`UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")`).

The output is this:

```
start
0
1
C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:1254: UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")
start
__mp_main__
start
__mp_main__
start
__mp_main__
```

I've tried uninstalling all required packages (numpy, smart_open), as well as gensim itself (in an active conda environment), but nothing has changed.
Also, what is the difference between the **main** and the multiprocessing one?

-- Specifications: win64, py 3.7.3

Edit: after running logging at the DEBUG level, logging file

```
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:start: :13396 
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:0 :13396 
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:1 :13396 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,493:start: :22356 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,493:3 :22356 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,496:start: :25332 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,497:3 :25332 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,530:start: :7120 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,530:3 :7120 
2020-02-16 22:49:01,541:adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens: []):13396
```

(also, the '3' was added in the `else` branch:)

```
else:
    logging.debug('3 ')
```

Comment: I wouldn't be sure that `chunkize` warning has anything to do with the problem. What if you run with logging at DEBUG level, is there any more indication of progress? What exact command-line do you execute? (I'm surprised there's an `__mp_main__` at all; that's not typical.)

Comment: @gojomo So, I tried doing that (also added 3 before the final print(__name__)) and it spit out this: 
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:start: :13396
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:0 :13396
2020-02-16 22:49:00,061:1 :13396
2020-02-16 22:49:01,493:start: :22356
2020-02-16 22:49:01,493:3 :22356
2020-02-16 22:49:01,496:start: :25332
2020-02-16 22:49:01,497:3 :25332
2020-02-16 22:49:01,530:start: :7120
2020-02-16 22:49:01,530:3 :7120
2020-02-16 22:49:01,541:adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens: []):13396

I used the regular Windows command prompt (but also tried Anaconda Prompt).

Comment: Can't really interpret that output in a comment; could you edit your question with the updated code/output, with formatting? An, with exactly what command-lines did you execute to get the output?

Comment: @gojomo of course! sorry about that - just updated it; and I used the `python <name_of_file>.py enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki_en.txt` command.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS may be a contributing factor; a lot of things related to multiprocessing work differently there, while `gensim` gets a lot more use & testing elsewhere. So if it is an option to test your code under another OS, or potentially use another OS entirely, this problem & other potential future problems may become irrelevant.

Other things to check & try:

- does the `wiki_en.txt` file get created, or receive any output, at all?
- does it help if you supply `processes=1` as an argument to `WikiCorpus`, so that only one worker process is used?
- if you tested some code that doesn't try using `WikiCorpus` at all, by tries to read-through the raw wiki dump, using `BZ2File` to uncompress it, in the same style as [gensim's `wikicorpus.py` source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/8d79794118a3adeda8cf9c873eb205cecf47cfef/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.py#L679), does that work, or also show a similar problem? (If there is a similar problem, then it's a usefully smaller triggering case that focuses attention on `BZ2File`'s operation on Windows.)
- are you by chance using [Wikipedia's "multistream" BZ2 file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Should_I_get_multistream?), and if so, could you try the non-multistream alternative & see if the same problem persists (in case this is an issue with `BZ2File` & multistream on Windows)?