# Does WikiCorpus from gensim library works on Arabic Wikipedia dump?

Tags: python, gensim

I see a code which uses Wikicorpus on an Arabic Wikipedia dump, and I know that the process will take a long time to execute, I also searched around about the warning that I get when executing it which says:

> (UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial
>   warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to
>   chunkize_serial"))

and answers said that it's ok, nothing serious, it's just a warning. 
But after waiting about 3 days without any response! I start wondering whether is it truly work on the Arabic dump file, or I have to do certain kind of pre-processing before passing the Arabic dump file to the Wikicorpus object?
the data size is about 989.6 MB.
and I surround the WikiCorpus code line with two print commands, to know when it started and when it finished executing, like this:

```
print('start WikiCorpus')
wiki = WikiCorpus(self.in_f)
print('finish WikiCorpus')
```

where the self.in_f is the Arabic Wikipedia dump like this: (/the path where the file located/arwiki-20200201-pages-articles.xml.bz2), but never reached the second print command during the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, especially if Arabic has clear word-delimiters (like spaces between words).

However, lots of things are harder on Windows, given that `gensim` & most related Python data-science libraries get more development/testing/use elsewhere, & there are some Windows-specific oddities with multiprocessing. If you have the option of working on another OS, that can make things easier.

There was another recent question describing a similar problem with an `en` dump & `WikiCorpus` – there are ideas of things to check in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60289555/130288), though it's unclear if the asker ever resolved the problem.

Also, when using code that relies on Python `multiprocessing` in Windows, it may be especially necessary to set your code off in a 'main' block that's won't be re-run if your file is re-imported by other processes, and call a Windows-specific `freeze_support()` function. See [some recent discussion of a related matter on the gensim project list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/-gMNdkujR48/i4Dn1_bjBQAJ).

Comment: Thank you! that's worked for me. My problem was as you mentioned in the third point. all I need is to set my code in a 'main' block and since I am missing this part, python re executes all the code again and inter in an infinite loop. 
It works even without using the freeze_support() statement.