# Runtime Error when running a LDA model of gensim, how can I fix it?

Tags: model, runtime-error, runtime, gensim, lda

I have an runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
  0%|          | 0/29 [00:48<?, ?it/s]
```

When I try run this code:

```
def topic_model_coherence_generator (corpus, texts, dictionary, start_topic_count=2, end_topic_count=10, step=1, cpus=1):
    models=[]
    coherence_scores = []
    for topic_nums in tqdm(range(start_topic_count, end_topic_count+1, step)):
        lda_model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=bow_corpus, id2word=dictionary, chunksize=1740, alpha='auto', eta='auto',
                                   random_state=42, iterations=500, num_topics=topic_nums, passes=20, eval_every=None)

        cv_coherence_model_lda = gensim.models.CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, corpus=bow_corpus,
                                                      texts=norm_corpus_bigrams, dictionary=dictionary,
                                                      coherence='c_v')

        coherence_score= cv_coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
        coherence_scores.append(coherence_score)
        models.append(lda_model)
    return models, coherence_scores

lda_models, coherence_scores = topic_model_coherence_generator(corpus=bow_corpus,
                                                               texts=norm_corpus_bigrams,
                                                               dictionary= dictionary,
                                                               start_topic_count=2,
                                                               end_topic_count=30,
                                                               step=1, cpus=16)
```

That I want is obtain the optimal number of topics of my corpus for obtain then the topics and interpreting topic model results. 
I'm biologist so I don't know how can I fix it. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

It's good practice, & might be required on Windows before using other code that uses Python `multiprocessing`, to put your code inside a 'main' block. See more details at answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459949/130288

(…& possibly the other answer it refers-back to).